# Unable to post to merchant API due to error saying I must provide a request body

Tags: c#, api

I spent all day trying to figure out what I was doing wrong yesterday.
Coming here to try and find some help.
The follow error is triggered when I run the actual GetResponse.
I am new to APIs so I am sure I am missing something real simple.

```
You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true. Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse.
```

Here is my code I am using to try and send JSON to the API. Payment object just has the form values entered in and the credentials to use the correct account on the merchants end.

```
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payment);
            var apiUrl = new Uri($"Removed endpoint URL");

            var postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            httpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

            //This is where the error triggers and drops to the catch.
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

I appreciate any help in advance, I may be doing this completely wrong, its a series of things I threw together trying to fix issues with the call.

Comment: have you checked out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed it, you're not actually writing your payload data to the `HttpWebRequest` body before you're sending it.

```
using (Stream _reqStrm = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
  _reqStrm.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
....
```

Unrelated but if you can, consider [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

Hth..

Comment: Thank you, you are right I completely missed that. I am able to post to the server now which is returning a 500 error, but now I can move on from here.